# You have requested a non-existent service "projet_rating.manager.rating"

Tags: symfony

I am getting the following error message: "`You have requested a non-existent service "projet_rating.manager.rating`" - Help please.

Comment: post the full error log (where usually is also showed the class where the service was called).

Comment: what mean please I didnt understand

Comment: could it be that you need have a typo in project?

Comment: I mean that in some point of the code is called a service that does not exist and usually in the Symfony2 profiler is shown in which class this service is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1) Somewhere in your application you have a controller that includes `$this->container->get("projet_rating.manager.rating")`

2) Somewhere in a config file you create a service that includes as an argument `%"projet_rating.manager.rating"%`.

If you're using an IDE that allows searching multiple files for a string, try searching for "projet_rating.manager.rating" in ...src/ or ...app/config

Comment: `%"projet_rating.manager.rating"%` is nothing and if it was something, it would be a parameter and not a service.

Comment: @WouterJ True for 2).  1) would give the service error.  I just got carried away remembering all the mistakes I made on my learning curve.

Comment: but I didn't find "projet_rating.manager.rating" in my project !!